# Unsupervised backup on remote ubuntu server

Tags: server, ssh, backup, owncloud-server

I'm running Ubuntu 22LTS on my work machine and I have an old computer on the side. I would like to make my old PC into a server and so far I have the know-how for installing the distribution and establish a key-secured connection through openssh.
I would like to use it as a backup/cloud server for myself, however before I start I would like to know if it's even possible to:

1. Automate backups on my work PC side, let's say everyday at 3am
2. Make it such that if a file on my work PC has not been accessed since the last backup, the aforementioned file gets ignored

I could do it "by hand", however before I complicate my life I would like to know if there's an easy/smart way to do that.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have weekly backup set up using the default Backup software that comes with Ubuntu. You can set up the option "storage Location" as **Network Server** and Network Location:  `sftp://server_username@hostname_of_old_computer_working_as_a_server.local/NetBackup/hostname_of_work_computer/your_username_in_work_computer`. Where `/NetBackup/hostname_of_work_computer/your_username_in_work_computer/` is the full path of the backup location.

Comment: if my comments work for you or if you need more detailed instructions, I can turn my comment to a full answer.

Comment: yes please, I'm new to this

Comment: Step 1: Learn how to connect to your server using ssh. Step 2: Learn how connect using key-based ssh. Step 3: Learn how to copy a file from machine #1 to machine #2 using the `rsync` application over ssh and then copy it back. Step 4: Learn how to rsync using key-based ssh triggered by a cron job. Step 5: Backup one file using `duplicity` over ssh, and then restore that file from the backup. Step 6: `duplicity` using key-based ssh triggered by a cron job. Finally Step 7: Backup your entire /home directory using key-based ssh triggered by a cron job.